# "Function expression, which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type" when adding void operation

Tags: typescript, function, void, any

I am having a strange issue on TypeScript. I recently learnt about `void ...` operator because I need to apply it so `eslint` wouldn't report `no-floating-promises`. However this particular snippet somehow caused an issue that **I cannot reproduce on TypeScript playground**:

```
class A {

  async a() {}

  async onTickAsync(repeat: boolean) {
    try {
      await this.a();
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    } finally {
      if (repeat) {
        window.setTimeout(() => void this.onTickAsync(true), 200);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

VS Code would report this error:

[image]

> TS7011: Function expression, which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.

However, the issue is not reproducible on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQTrUgTwHbHQCgEpEBfFNTHaAeywBUBLYAa1gm2DwCcBTAB27AAXAFzQARlSogBWIsjRpBnDIlQLyAdzD1B0QQAt6EAHRhCAbjVpi0YEOD683OVYXAaEKd2PdOnKpxOBJbqNgBm9FhgICAq8urQ9GHQXHwCgi4JChqRACZUGsYQ3IIMALbcVACugniE0AC8AHzQAG5U9Ll6hiY0DMys7HhKVc4ANNAATAAM08Gu1q6ki0jEQA). Both VS Code and Playground is using TypeScript 4.5.4. Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "ESNext"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I understand it can be fixed by adding `: void` return type or removing `void` operation or removing `noImplicitAny`:

```
window.setTimeout((): void => void this.onTickAsync(true), 200);
```

I want to ask: What causes the error? Why is it happening only on my IDE/local and not the playground?

---

To be sure it's not just due to VS Code, I ran `tsc --version` and `tsc` on a separate Terminal as well:

[image]

`tsc --showConfig` output:

```
PS C:\Users\lukev\Downloads\Temp> tsc --showConfig
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext"
    },
    "files": [
        "./test.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

It's also interesting that it doesn't happen to other function. This, for example, does not produce any error. It seems to be something with `window.setTimeout`. I found out there is something different between `Function` type and `() => void` for example):

```
class A {

  doSomething1(_: Function) { }
  doSomething2(_: () => any) { }
  doSomething3(_: () => void) { }

  async a() { }

  async onTickAsync(repeat: boolean) {
    // Only this one produces error
    this.doSomething1(() => void this.onTickAsync(true));
    this.doSomething2(() => void this.onTickAsync(true));
    this.doSomething3(() => void this.onTickAsync(true));
  }

}
```

Comment: @LukeVo Will you include the output of [`tsc --showConfig`](https://www.staging-typescript.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#the-new---showconfig-flag) in your question?

Comment: @jsejcksn didn't know that command. Added.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder exactly like in your screenshot. `4.5.4 — TypeScript version`.  Also I think it's not due to VS Code since it happens to independent terminal as well.

Comment: Well that seems really definitive. :-) (I misunderstood your earlier comment about running `tsc` separately; I get it now.) Thanks!

Comment: I found out it has something to do with `setTimeout` using `TimerHandler = string | Function` as its parameter type. Could be something difference between Playground and my `lib.dom.d.ts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#36651](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36651) for an authoritative answer.

Your issue is that you have enabled [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noImplicitAny) but you have *not* enabled [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictNullChecks).  You can set these options in the TypeScript Playground [and reproduce your issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQTrUgTwHbHQCgEpFoBfFNTHaAeywBUBLYAa1gm2DwCcBTABx5gALgC5oAI2rUQgrEWRo0QrhkSpFFAO5gGQ6EIAWDCADowhANzq0JaMGHAD0PD3nXFwWhGk8TPLlzUXC4EVhq2AGYMWGAgIKoKGtAMEc68AsJuSYqa0QAm1JomEDxCjAC2PNQArkJ4hNAAvAB80ABu1Ax5+kamtIwsbBx4ytWuADTQAEwADDOh7jbuZEtIJEA).

Aside: note that `--strictNullChecks` is part of [the `--strict` family of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict), which is generally recommended as part of a de facto "standard" level of type safety.  You're not really asking about which compiler options you should use, but do note that if you use an uncommon set of compiler options you are more likely to run into compiler behavior that is not well known to the general TypeScript community.  Okay, enough about that.

So we know how to reproduce, but haven't explicitly answered *why* there's an error here.  Let's do that now.  With `--strictNullChecks` enabled, [the `void` opterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) produces a value of [the `undefined` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined).  But with `--strictNullChecks` *disabled*, there isn't really a distinct `undefined` type, and the `void` operator produces a value of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  And unless you explicitly [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) that a type is `any`, you'll get an error under `--noImplicitAny`:

```
// with --strictNullChecks disabled

() => void 0; // error!
// Function expression, which lacks return-type annotation, 
// implicitly has an 'any' return type.

(): undefined => void 0; // okay
//^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- arrow function return type annotation
```

As you saw, you can also get rid of the error if the return type of the `void` operator is given a [contextual type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing):

```
function foo(cb: () => any) { }
foo(() => void 0); // okay, void 0 is contextually typed as any
```

And note that the `Function` interface is a bit strange and doesn't have a true [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures), see [microsoft/TypeScript#20007](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20007), so it can't provide a contextual type:

```
function bar(cb: Function) { }
bar(() => void 0); // implicit any error!
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/PTAEHcEsBcAtQLQIM7QE6QMbQHIFcAbAgYVgFNMBrZUAE0mQEMAjAs2gKA4AoBKUALwA+UADcA9pFqgADAG5QIUGTRpxaAIQclAMTwA7bJHH7lADwAOaMsmTH9AGgiws8Aoyo1r0PGn0JoAE8LMlBGfX1xaEZoeydtMEgAWwsCLBgCQNBYRhpw0ABycMCC0G9fUyCQgDouJXDI6Oh2Hl4ALlADWjIAM0h9dkERCSlZBSVxSkZAurBME2azH0YCDh6DIxNQHvFxbkxmDr4hsP1A-gBvUABfNd3uY+ExSWkZXjkudcNYreZGNH2h1Aem+9kuNw4fwBj2GL1k70UiRSaUwMFOWRUak0HCAA)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. The aside note is very helpful actually, I didn't know about that. I will definitely use that flag for my future projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot,
this code fixed it:
`"noImplicitAny": false, "strictNullChecks": false,`

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue and, although I can't answer **why** this is happening, you can fix the compiler error by omitting the [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void), and chaining a `catch` method to the promise to satisfy ESLint:

```ts
// before
window.setTimeout(() => void this.onTickAsync(true), 200);

// after
window.setTimeout(() => this.onTickAsync(true).catch(() => {}), 200);
```

Comment: I am not the one downvoting but I did explain in my question that I know how to fix it. Also sometimes it's actually dangerous to remove it since function returned values could change callback behavior in the future (see [description of void operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)). In that case, adding explicit `: void` return type is more favorable :)

Comment: @LukeVo I was just offering another suggestion which you didn't mention that satisfies both the compiler and ESLint.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't notice that. I added an upvote though I think simply adding `: void` is still simpler (and still have the `void` operator) and I don't need the `catch` if I have `void` operator.

Comment: @LukeVo No worries. My suggestion also _actually_ prevents an unhandled promise rejection (which is what that ESLint rule you are using is trying to help you prevent).

Comment: @jsejcksn - The OP's `onTickAsync` never rejects its promise (unless `window.setTimeout` throws an error, which I think we can assume it never does).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Of course that's right as its written, but ESLint can't determine that (and the function body might change in a way that changes that statement).

Comment: @jsejcksn - No, but the OP can, and can decide to use `void` rather than a pointless `catch`. The function is clearly written never to reject.

Comment: Yes, many ways to solve this problem.