# component which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't understand this typescript error that I'm getting saying:

> 'MyGoogleLogin', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.

I just want the component to receive an anonymous function with void return type as props and I'm frustrated about this typescript error because I can't find the correct syntax to do this simple thing.

```
function MyGoogleLogin({setModal: () => void}) {
  const router = useRouter()
    return (
        <GoogleLogin
            onSuccess={(credentialResponse: CredentialResponse) => {
                let jwt = credentialResponse.credential
                if (!jwt) {
                    return;
                }
                handleLogin(jwt)
            }}
            onError={() => {
                console.log('Login Failed');
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

edit: This question is NOT a duplicate. I have not configured any particular compiler options. The solutions in the proposed "duplicate" question to not apply to my situation. I've also added a photo which shows that setting "any" to the return type does not solve the issue.

[image]

Comment: This message is about component function, not its prop. Try doing this: `function MyGoogleLogin({setModal: () => void}): any {`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Function expression, which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type" when adding void operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70649907/function-expression-which-lacks-return-type-annotation-implicitly-has-an-any)
Seems like you have errors in TypeScript configuration as stated in the accepted answer

Comment: @KonradLinkowski It's not supposed to return any type though, it usually knows that the return type should be JSX.Element. If I set the return type to JSX.Element, I still get that error message

Comment: I don't have any specific compiler options enabled which is what the answer seems to suggest is the source of the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution I wanted, but the only workaround currently is to define my own inteface for my props:

```
interface LoginProps {
  setModal: (enabled: boolean) => void
}

function MyGoogleLogin({setModal}: LoginProps) {
  const router = useRouter()
    return (
        <GoogleLogin
            onSuccess={(credentialResponse: CredentialResponse) => {
                let jwt = credentialResponse.credential
                if (!jwt) {
                    return;
                }
                handleLogin(jwt)
            }}
            onError={() => {
                console.log('Login Failed');
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

Defining an interface here seems like it shouldn't be necessary but whatever.  If someone has a better solution feel free to share.